# What is the cheapest Cash-to-Bitcoin Service?

Tags: services, banks

There seems to be a few services to purchase bitcoins from out there, as in bitinstant, MtGox, bitcoin.de, etc.

I would like to know if someone has looked around to find the one with the cheapest transaction fees for buying/selling bitcoins.

Comment: The factors relevant to providing the right advice include:

Where are you located (country)? How much are you looking to buy? What payment methods do you have available? How soon do you need access to the proceeds? Is privacy important?

Comment: I am located in europe, payment options include CC, paypal, SEPA transfer and cash, while paypal itself already charges fees for transactions. Privacy is preferred, but trust is more important. The amounts of selling/buying will be low for now, until I have trust in the system.

Comment: This question is currently too localised, and will likely become out of date. Have raised the issue for discussion here (http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/311/cheapest-question-will-get-out-of-date), but perhaps the question should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would probably be either [Bitcoin OTC](http://bitcoin-otc.com/) or [Local Bitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/), as you are trading directly between people. This way you can barter for better rates and you don't have to pay a fee.

Answer (score 6):

In the U.S., the least expensive method is a Dwolla transfer to an exchange that accepts Dwolla (Mt. Gox, and Camp BX).  Dwolla charges $0.25 per transaction when the amount transferred is over $10.

Quite simply, depositing cash at a bank or 7-11, Walmart, CVS is going to be the fastest and easiest way.

One method that was the least expensive, depositing cash at an exchange's bank, is currently unavailable as the exchange that offered that (BitFloor) has suspended that method, temporarily apparently.

BitMe offers this but they don't have much liquidity yet (on the sell side) so that might not work.

If you are looking to deposit $500 or more, then Bitcoins Direct will accept that cash:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=87094.0 (Deposit cash at Bank of America, Wells Fargo or PNC, minimum $500)

All other cash deposit options:

- http://www.BitInstant.com (Deposit at major banks, 7-11, Walmart, CVS, Moneygram, etc.,)
- http://www.BitMe.com (Deposit cash at Chase)
- http://www.BitFloor.com (Deposit cash at Chase or Wells Fargo)
- http://www.bitinnovate.com (Deposit cash at a bank in Australia & New Zealand)
- http://www.CAVirtEx.com (Deposit cash at several banks)
- http://www.Spendbitcoins.com (Deposit cash at a bank in Australia)
- http://BitcoinNordic.com (Purchase CashU or UKash in dozens of countries)
- http://www.BTC-E.com (Deposit cash (USD) at bank locations in Russia)
- http://www.BitNZ.om (Deposit cash (NZD) at back locations in New Zealand)
- http://www.BitInstant.com (In Brazil using Boleto or Banco Recomendito, or in Russia, using Qiwi or Cyberplat.)
- http://www.bitXoin.com (Deposit cash over the teller at Major Australian Bank Branches)

Alternatives:

If you are in the U.S., there is one vendor that apparently is offering to sell via credit card.

- https://www.quickbitcoins.net

The fees aren't trivial but you can use a credit card to purchase by using VirWoX where you can buy SLL using your credit card, then trade SLL for BTC:

- http://www.VirWoX.com

There possibly are other options that will work for you as well:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

Last of all there is #bitcoin-otc where you can connect with sellers via IRC:

- http://bitcoin-otc.com/

Answer (score 1):

For SEPA transfers, [Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/) may be what you want. I've been using it for months now. There is no deposit fee (just what you pay to your bank for the SEPA transfer), and you pay up to 0.5 % fee when you buy BTC (this was actually free last week but you missed it). There is also some currency conversion expense (your EUR will be converted to USD), but they use ECB's currency rates which are quite good, and don't take any fees themselves for conversion. Also the exchange is quite liquid (third largest USD market) so the spread won't cost you much either.

If you're just buying BTC, this is it. If you plan to withdraw EUR from the exchange, you'll also pay 0.90 EUR per withdrawal.

Also all SEPA transfers are processed in 24 hours, sometimes the same day.